# Reading data from a xml file inside HTML CDATA with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to read data in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<![CDATA[sample content]]><br />
<![CDATA[more content]]><br />
<![CDATA[content]]><br /></body>
```

the data comes from a remote xml file so I cannot alter it. I've trying to read this with php using

```
$file = file_get_contents($r[0]->overview);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($file); 

echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

This outputs:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[br] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

    )

)
```

I'm unsure how to read the contents, normally I could see an array or object I can loop through.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<![CDATA[sample content]]>` should be encased in a opening and a closing tag , only then the data can be retrieved. Also, to read the `CDATA` content , you should use the `LIBXML_NOCDATA` parameter.

Since those `CDATA` did not have any proper encasement you were getting the empty array.

#### The fixed code..

```
<?php

$content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<![CDATA[sample content]]><br />
<![CDATA[more content]]><br />
<![CDATA[content]]><br /></body>';

$content = str_replace(array('<br />','<!',']>'),array('','<br><!',']></br>'),$content);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
print_r($xml);
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [br] => Array
        (
            [0] => sample content
            [1] => more content
            [2] => content
        )

)
```

Comment: any workaround? as I cannot change the remote xml files only read them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just SimpleXMLs magic. CDATA sections are a special kind of text nodes, they allow to write the special characters in XML without the encoding (<, >, ", '). This has two reasons: backwards compatibility for the script elements and better human readability.

They are still nodes and can be read as such:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<![CDATA[sample content]]><br />
<![CDATA[more content]]><br />
<![CDATA[content]]><br /></body>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// iterate all text child nodes that are not just whitespaces
foreach($xpath->evaluate('/body/text()[normalize-space(.) != ""]') as $node) {
  var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(.)', $node));
}
```

Output: https://eval.in/140237

```
string(14) "sample content"
string(12) "more content"
string(7) "content"
```